# A dumb question about $T_2$ space-Looking for alternative proof

Tags: general-topology, alternative-proof

Show that R is Hausdorff
[image]

I have a proof for it
I want to know is there anyway to do it
using set theory alone

For instance the distance between two sets ,
say U and V the formula is inf{||x-y||,x$\in $U,y$\in$V}

I don’t want to rely on the above too

Any hints would be nice?
Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you really want.  Given $a \neq b \in \mathbb{R}$, just consider the open intervals of radius $|a-b|/4$ about $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I saw a radius of |a-b|/2 givesn too. For instance describing radii and distance in pure set theoretic notation

Comment: I don't know what that means, to describe distance purely with set theory.

Comment: @Homer Take $d=|a-b|/2$ and consider the intervals $U = (a-d,a+d)$ and $V = (b-d,b+d)$.

Comment: Alright,thanks @Randall

Comment: The definition of a Topological Space is very broad. Not all of them can be described in terms of a distance-function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show that $\Bbb R$ is Hausdorff, you can use different approaches: it is a metric space $(X,d)$ and any metric space is Hausdorff:

Let $x \neq y \in X$. Then $r:=d(x,y)>0$ by properties of the metric. Define $s=\frac{r}{2}>0$.
Then $U=B_s(x)$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$ and $V = B_s(y)$ is an open neighbourhood of $y$ and $U \cap V = \emptyset$, for otherwise there would be some $z \in B_s(x) \cap B_s(y)$, so $d(z,x) < s$ and $d(z,y) < s$ and then

$$d(x,y) \le d(x,z) +d(z,y) < s + s =2s = r= d(x,y)$$

which is a contradiction. Hence $(X,d)$ is Hausdorff in the metric topology.

Aother approach is to use that the topology on $\Bbb R$ is induced by its linear order: and $(X,<)$ in the order topology is Hausdorff:

Let $x \neq y$ in $X$. WLOG we can assume $x < y$ (or we interchange the roles of $x$ and $y$).

Case 1:if there is some $z \in X$ such that $x < z < y$ (as will be the case in $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb Q$, e.g.), then $x \in U:=(\leftarrow, z)$ and $y \in V:=(z,\rightarrow)$ are subbasic open in the order topology and $U \cap V = \emptyset$.

Case 2: if no such $z$ exists, we can define $U:=(\leftarrow, y), V := (x, \rightarrow)$ to be difjoint open (sub)basic open neighbourhoods of $x$ resp. $y$.

So we can prove the fact that $\Bbb R$ is Hausdorff on two possible ways to generate the topology on this set, either by metric (which is Morris' preferred way) or by order.

Comment: Morris doesn’t introduce metric spaces to chapter 6. Can I the Euclidean topology.

Comment: @Homer He uses the absolute value doesn't he? Well, read $|x-y|$ for $d(x,y)$ and the proof remains the same. Or does he use intervals as a base? In that case the order proof is easily adapted.

Comment: He uses intervals mainly